# the question of what time to be <at> there <at>

Tags: prepositions, content-clauses

[thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+up):
**(1)** *The question of what time to be there never came up*.
my versions:
**(2)** *The question of what time to be **at** there never came up*.
**(3)** *The question of what time to be there **at** never came up*.

Are (2) & (3) grammatical?
Do (1), (2) & (3) mean the same?

**Additional possibilities**

4. The question of the time to be there never came up.
5. The question of the time to be there at never came up.
6. The question of the time at which to be there never came up.

Are (4), (5) and (6) correct?

Comment: #2 definitely does not sound grammatical or natural.  *there* is already an adverb of position, so "at there" is redundant and unnatural.  #3 sounds natural in my dialect (New York City) but I am curious to see what others say...

Comment: I think this may be cause 'there' is being used instead of a specific place. It's fine to say "The question of what time to be _at_ the bank never came up", but when you use "there" it replaces the whole "at the bank", not just "the bank" - so I would say (1) is correct as is. Also you may be mixing up **at** for a time, and **at** for a location - "The question of _at_ what time to be _at_ the bank never came up"

Comment: Another option: *the question of when to be there*.

Comment: Why do you think any of those versions might be correct? The word "at" is a preposition. Do you think "there" or "never" are nouns?

Answer (score 4):

2 & 3 are not grammatically correct English. The "**at**" is in the wrong place.
1 is probably the best, but if you insist on inserting an "at" then

> The question of **at** what time to be there never came up.

is about the best you can do, but "at" isn't necessary.

Comment: It might be strictly 'more correct' but no-one would ever use it in speech. They'd use the OP's option 3, just because there's too much mental hoop to jump to know to put it so early in the sentence when you set off cold. [& If I had thought about that sentence before I set off, I'd have used 'in knowing'. See how the brain works? ;)

Comment: @DoneWithThis. You made me go back and read your sentence again.  The first time I didn’t notice there are 3 infinitives in a row!  :)

Comment: @QuackE.Duck: Well, don't copy it! To my mind the sentence was already in trouble with *there's too much mental hoop to jump,* and couldn't be saved anyway!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I spend half my life torturing the language for fun ;))

Comment: @DoneWithThis.: English will still be there when we're dead and buried. But if technology a few centuries hence is good enough to resuscitate us, we'll probably have a really hard time understanding the language of the future. I don't know if professional linguists know (or have opinions about it), but I'm inclined to suspect English is changing faster than ever today. Perhaps you torturing it is like a harsh environment in evolutionary terms - change or die!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - There is, indeed, still a great sea change. [I was 30 before I fully understood that joke in its original form, knowing nothing previously about vowel-shits or anything similar]. Being a Yorkshireman, of course, my own vowel-shifts from those of RP can be pretty spectacular in themselves.

Comment: @DoneWithThis: I got a memorable illustration of the pace of change at age 11, within just a few weeks of moving from primary to secondary school. The English teacher had us sit through several minutes of Chaucer's Canterbury Tales read in what was supposed to be the authentic accents of the time. I kid you not - there were at least 30 of us in the class, and *nobody* had the faintest idea what was being said! Luckily we never went near Chaucer again, but an awful lot of even Shakespeare is obscure / impenetrable to the modern ear.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - we had a brief flirtation with Chaucer in school too - the teacher attempted to read it to us in 'the original' and we had books with facing pages in old & new English. I don't think we were convinced at the age of 14 or so. Probably put me off for life, I've not been near it since.

Comment: **(4)** _The question of **the** time to be there never came up_. --||-- **(5)** _The question of **the** time to be there **at** never came up_. --||-- **(6)** _The question of **the** time **at which** to be there never came up_.  Are (4), (5) and (6) correct? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii 4 & 6 are OK, 5 is not. Same sort of reasoning as in my answer and the resultant comments. But please do not ask questions in the comments, edit your question and make a note of the edit here.

Comment: @PeterJennings "_edit your question and make a note of the edit here_" - if I had done so, moderators would have been against it because they would have considered what I asked you in the comments a new question not relating to the original one.

Comment: @Loviii No, I meant edit your original post by adding the new questions to it, then make a note in the comments that you have done so. You shouldn't really ask further questions in the comments other than for clarification, neither should you post them as an answer as I have seen done elsewhere.

Comment: @Loviii I've done it for you so that you know what to do in future.

Comment: @PeterJennings Thank you for help. Though I think moderators won't be happy when seeing such additions to the original post. At least when I did so in other my threads they asked me not to do it.

Comment: @Loviii Maybe, but they certainly don't like additional questions in comments either!! Which of your questions was it? I can have a look and see if I think I've done it wrong.